# Не удается найти факториал числа

Tags: python, циклы

Учу `Python`. Решаю задачу, в которой нужно позволить пользователю ввести неотрицательное целое значение, затем применить цикл для вычисления факториала этого числа и вывести его на экран. Но на последней строке срабатывает `SyntaxError`.

Код:

```
num = int(input('Введите неотрицательное целое число: '))
while num <= 0 or num % 1 != 0:
    print('Ошибка')
    num = int(input('Введите неотрицательное целое число: '))
for x in range(num):
    fact = num * (num - (num- (x+1))
    print(fact)
```

Лог:

```
File "<ipython-input-7-6d70e7b9ea80>", line 7
    print(fact)
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Понял ошибки:

- забыл скобку
- формулу факториала вобще не нужно было использовать. Все сделал через введение накопителя с изначальным значением 1.0:

  ```
    num = int(input('Введите неотрицательное целое число: '))
    while num <= 0 or num % 1 != 0:
        print('Ошибка')
        num = int(input('Введите неотрицательное целое число: '))
    total = 1.0
    for x in range(num):
        total *= (x+1)
    print(total)
  ```

Comment: вам нужно использовать не ```num <= 0```, а ```num < 0```. А еще лучше использовать не ```x+1```, а ```range(1, num+1)```

Comment: А можете пож весь код привести?

Answer (score 1):

```
num = int(input('Введите неотрицательное целое число: '))
while num <= 0 or num % 1 != 0:
    print('Ошибка')
    num = int(input('Введите неотрицательное целое число: '))
for x in range(num):
    fact = num * (num - (num - x)) # скобку забыли :D
print(fact)
```

А так то не понимаю зачем вы x + 1 в выражении используете

Answer (score 1):

```
num = int(input('Введите неотрицательное целое число: '))
while num < 0:
  print('Ошибка')
  num = int(input('Введите неотрицательное целое число: '))
fact = 1
for x in range(2, num+1):
  fact *= x
print(fact)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]